# Dashboard graph showing orders, but no amount

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, dashboard

We just migrated our webshop to a new domain.

Now, whenever an order is placed, the order **does** show up in the admin dashboard graph as order, but **doesn't** show op in the amounts tab. Also revenue is displayed as 0.

The transaction is not canceled, we have received the money and the order status was processing and is now shipped. Before the migration, everything worked like a charm.

We also upgraded from magento 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.4.

I tried the aggregated data setting, it is set to no. The google api is correct in `Graph.php`. I also tried the `getChartUrl` from `false` to `true`, but no luck there.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: If you process it to "completed" state, it may be considered in the amounts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing the reports statistics?

You can do it by Navigating to "Reports->Refresh Statistics" on admin panel.

Hope it will help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the money was not capture. Check in the invoice tab of one order and see if the order is pending or compleate. If its pending check if the payment was captured.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query which can calculate the amount you need:

```
SELECT ABS(SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) main_table.base_to_global_rate)) AS `lifetime`, ABS(AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) main_table.base_to_global_rate)) AS `average` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.status NOT IN('Canceled')) AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new', 'pending_payment'))
```